# Getting the error "cannot be resolved as a variable" for the code below

Tags: java, data-structures, driver

The appointmentP1, appointmentP2 and appointmentP3 are all giving me the error for the doctor instance. As well as the notesP1-P5 for the patient instance.

```
package controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import model.Appointment;
import model.Doctor;
import model.DoctorList;
import model.Notes;
import model.Patient;
import model.PatientList;
import view.MainGUI;

public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Doctor d1 = new Doctor("D1", "Dr. ", "Wyatt", "(Cardiology)", appointmentP1); 
        Doctor d2 = new Doctor("D2", "Dr. ", "Brandanowitz", "(Respiratory Therapy)", appointmentP2);
        Doctor d3 = new Doctor("D3", "Dr. ", "Perkins", "(Obstetrics & Gynocology)", appointmentP3);
        
        DoctorList dlist = new DoctorList(); 
        dlist.Insert(d1);
        dlist.Insert(d2);
        dlist.Insert(d3);
        
        Patient p1 = new Patient("P1", 51, "Leslie ", "Knope", "9/16/1971", notesP1); 
        Patient p2 = new Patient("P2", 52, "Ron ", "Swanson", "6/26/1970", notesP2); 
        Patient p3 = new Patient("P3", 38, "April ", "Ludgate", "6/26/1984", notesP3); 
        Patient p4 = new Patient("P4", 43, "Andy ", "Dwyer", "6/21/1979", notesP4); 
        Patient p5 = new Patient("P5", 53, "Donna ", "Meagle", "4/20/1970", notesP5); 
        
        PatientList plist = new PatientList(); 
        plist.Insert(p1);
        plist.Insert(p2);
        plist.Insert(p3);
        plist.Insert(p4);
        plist.Insert(p5);
    
        
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.printf("%1$s %2$tB %2$td, %2$tY", "Appointment date:", date);
        
        
        
        //LESLIE
        Appointment apptP1 = new Appointment("A1", date, d3, p1);
        Appointment apptP2 = new Appointment("A2", date, d3, p1);
        
        //RON
        Appointment apptP3 = new Appointment("A3", date, d1, p2);
        Appointment apptP4 = new Appointment("A4", date, d1, p2);
        Appointment apptP5 = new Appointment("A5", date, d1, p2);
        
        //APRIL
        Appointment apptP6 = new Appointment("A6", date, d3, p3);
        
        //ANDY
        Appointment apptP7 = new Appointment("A7", date, d1, p4);
        Appointment apptP8 = new Appointment("A8", date, d1, p4);
        
        //DONNA
        Appointment apptP9 = new Appointment("A9", date, d2, p5);
        Appointment apptP10 = new Appointment("A10", date, d2, p5);
        
        
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentP1 = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        appointmentP1.add(apptP1);
        appointmentP1.add(apptP2);
        
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentP2 = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        appointmentP2.add(apptP3);
        appointmentP2.add(apptP4);
        appointmentP2.add(apptP5);
        
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentP3 = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        appointmentP3.add(apptP6);
        
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentP4 = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        appointmentP4.add(apptP7);
        appointmentP4.add(apptP8);
        
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentP5 = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        appointmentP5.add(apptP9);
        appointmentP5.add(apptP10);
        
    
    
    
        Notes n1 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P1");
        Notes n2 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P1");
        Notes n3 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P1");
        Notes n4 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P1");
        Notes n5 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P2");
        Notes n6 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P2");
        Notes n7 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P2");
        Notes n8 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P2");
        Notes n9 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P3");
        Notes n10 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P3");
        Notes n11 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d3, "P3");
        Notes n12 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P4");
        Notes n13 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P4");
        Notes n14 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d1, "P4");
        Notes n15 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d2, "P5");
        Notes n16 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d2, "P5");
        Notes n17 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d2, "P5");
        Notes n18 = new Notes("patient note goes here", d2, "P5");
        
        ArrayList<Notes> notesP1 = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        notesP1.add(n1);
        notesP1.add(n2);
        notesP1.add(n3);
        notesP1.add(n4);
        
        ArrayList<Notes> notesP2 = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        notesP2.add(n5);
        notesP2.add(n6);
        notesP2.add(n7);
        notesP2.add(n8);
        
        ArrayList<Notes> notesP3 = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        notesP3.add(n9);
        notesP3.add(n10);
        notesP3.add(n11);
        
        ArrayList<Notes> notesP4 = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        notesP4.add(n12);
        notesP4.add(n13);
        notesP4.add(n14);
        
        ArrayList<Notes> notesP5 = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        notesP5.add(n15);
        notesP5.add(n16);
        notesP5.add(n17);
        notesP5.add(n18);
                
    }

}
```

No matter where I place them in code, something errors out. I even tried making them global variables and that didn't work. Any advise would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: You're trying to use variables before they've been declared or assigned a value...

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependencies, ie:

```
A Doctor requires an appointment list

An appointment list requires appointments 

An appointment requires a Doctor.
```

Remove the 4th argument from the `Doctor` constructor `(List<Appointment>)` and define a setter for the appointments list in the `Doctor` class `setAppointments(List<Appointment> appointments)`. Use this setter after the appointmentP1, etc have been created, eg:

```
d1.setAppointments(appointmentP1);
```

Also, it is always better to declare a variable with the interface name and instantiate with a class, and to infer the generic type with <> eg:

```
List<Appointment> appointmentP1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

The above with fix your “cannot be resolved as a variable “ problem but I think your data structure is weird. I would remove appointment list from Doctor and generate it for a Doctor from all the appointments.